# Javascript: Construct an object from array of objects based on matching property id's:

Tags: javascript, object, key, higher-order-functions

still quite new to higher order functions and trying to use them correctly here if possible.

I have a array of objects being returned from an api constructed like so:

```
[ {"gymId":3467, "halls": [{ "hallId": "25828", "instructorId": 1064, 
   "slotIds": [2088,2089], "sessionId":8188}, 
  {"hallId": "25848", "instructorId": 1067, "slotIds": [2088,2089], "sessionId": 8188 }]}]
```

Expected result I want to achieve is to create a list of objects such as this from the array above ...

```
{2088: [{ "hallId":"25828", "instructorId":1064, "sessionId":8188 }, 
        { "hallId":"25848", "instructorId":1067, "sessionId":8188 }],
 2089: [{ "hallId":"25828", "instructorId":1064, "sessionId":8188 }, 
        { "hallId":"25848", "instructorId":1067, "sessionId":8188 }] 
}
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this

```
halls.reduce((acc, hall) => {
      hall.slotIdIds.forEach(slotId => {
        acc[slotId] = {
          //expected object properties as above here.
        };
      });
      return acc;
    }, {}),
```

Problem is when I reduce in this way only one hallId is being returned and not the two matching hall ids where the slots exist.

Bit perplexed as to how to solve this one and would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: You're using acc[slotId] instead of push or adding, so it replaces the other ones?

Comment: Looks like `acc[slotId]` should be an array into which you add one or more objects.

Comment: If I don't know what the slot id will be before hand how would i add it to an object to be a key in the format as above e.g
{2088: [{ "hallId":"25828", "instructorId":1064, "sessionId":8188 }, 
        { "hallId":"25848", "instructorId":1067, "sessionId":8188 }], ?